# How do I know which dynamic Toggle Button was clicked in android

Tags: android, dynamic, android-edittext, android-togglebutton

I am creating 10 editText and 10 Toggle Button dynamically in android. 
I have done this part, but I want some more advancements in it. The snippet is like:

```
for(int i =0 ; i < 10; i++) {
     et=new EditText(context);
     et.setLayoutParams(lprams); 
     et.setKeyListener(null);
     et.setClickable(true);
     et.setId(1); 
     et.setText(lwfb.get(i));
     et.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
     final ToggleButton tb = new ToggleButton(context);
     tb.setTextOn("ON");
     tb.setTextOff("OFF");
     tb.setChecked(true);
     tb.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

     ll.addView(et);
     ll.addView(tb);

     tb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             if(tb.isChecked()){
                 //Button is ON
             } else {
                 //Button is OFF
             }    
        }
    });
}
```

Where `ll` is the Dynamic `LinearLayout` variable.

I want to achieve two things:

1. Display both Edit Text and Toggle Button of same index in same line.
2. In place of `//Button is ON/OFF` I want to display `button [i] is ON/OFF`.

Comment: not getting EditText and `ToggleButton ` in same line?

Comment: Down Voter give the reason for your vote.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK : Display EditText and ToggleButton on same line like in relative layout.

Comment: Now can anyone help me solve the first issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ll` has probably a vertical orientation, which means, that the items added to the layout will appear one under another. To put the `EditText` and the `ToggleButton` in the same line, you have to put them in another layout - you can use another `LinearLayout` with horizontal orientation. Then instead of adding `EditText` and `ToggleButton` directly to `ll`, you add them to this new layout and then you add this new layout to `ll`.

```
LinearLayout line = new LinearLayout(context);
line.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
line.addView(et);
line.addView(tb);
ll.addView(line);
```

You might also want to set layout parameters and other things to make some alignments.

Answer (score 2):

You could add a [tag](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag(int,%20java.lang.Object)) to your created view and use it to identify your button.

```
private static final int TAG_KEY_POS = R.id.someid;

...
tb.setTag(TAG_KEY_POS, i);
...
```

You can retrieve the value later with

```
(Integer) view.getTag(TAG_KEY_POS);
```

Comment: Rudiger ~ I got an error, The method setTag(int,Object) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (String,int)

Comment: Thats fine @Rudiger. But now I got an runtime exception,  the key must be an application specific resource id.

Comment: heh yeah noticed that. Okay You just need to use a resource identifier.. mostly any will suffice like the name of a button you created with +@id/.... if you want to be more specific have a look at: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Id

Comment: Thanks @Rudiger, thats worked like a charm ! 

Created a file tags.xml in values folder with content 
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <item name="TAG_KEY_POS" type="id"/>
    </resources>
and accessed it as R.id.TAG_KEY_POS .
It did the trick.